# Swift - UICollectionView dynamic height

Tags: swift

I'm trying to change the height of UICollectionView by the number of cells.

The cell height is 25 and line spacing between the cells is 10.

I want to allow a user to press add more cell button and when it's tapped, I want to increase the height of the UICollectionView.

These are my codes below:

```
import UIKit

class TestController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        let cellWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 25)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return collectionView
    }()

    var numberOfCells = 1

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfCells
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        return cell
    }

    let addMoreCellButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Add more cell", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addMoreCell), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = falase
        return button
    }()

    @objc func addMoreCell() {
        numberOfCells += 1
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(numberOfCells * 35 - 10)).isActive = true
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(addMoreCellButton)
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    }

}
```

In the function addMoreCell() I changed the height but I get this message in the console.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028d020 UICollectionView:0x7fddfe206000.height == 25   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028aeb0 UICollectionView:0x7fddfe206000.height == 60   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028aeb0 UICollectionView:0x7fddfe206000.height == 60   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: That's not how you work with `UICollectionView`. You don't change the width/height of collection view itself, instead change the item's size. First learn how to work with collection view properly.

Comment: I wanted to add UIViews and text fields in the same page. That’s why I need to change the height and I can change the height statically but not dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I had done similar type of thing where more increase collection Height. with Dynamic collectionView just give this class to your collectionView . Reload collectionView with increase collectionView height dynamically and scroll the content below if constraint are right. Hope it help.

```
class DynamicCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if bounds.size != intrinsicContentSize {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }
}
```

// another patch

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  isAllCategoriesShowned ? homeViewModel.categories.count:   numberOfCategoriesShownByDefault
  }
```

Comment: can u debug what happens ?

Comment: I fixed the issue by myself today. Setting the duplicated heightAnchor was the problem so I removed the constraint in addMoreCell() by using removeConstraint(_:). Thank you for your help anyways!